# "Hello World" for a Joomla web service?

Tags: web-services, joomla, xml-rpc

I'd like to write a small web service in Joomla for a client, but I'm not sure how to get started. Although I'm moderately familiar with Joomla and quite comfortable with web services, I'm a complete stranger to web services in Joomla.

Is there a "hello, world" example that anyone's aware of, or could demonstrate in an answer? Sometimes I've also seen a calculator web service as the "hello, world" example, where you support various operations like `Add`, `Subtract`, et cetera.

I'm using the latest Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Good luck. I was never able to found good documentation on how to develop third party for Joomla... Only tips & tricks & hacks which make the code messy..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend [James Kennard, *Mastering Joomla! 1.5*](http://www.packtpub.com/joomla-one-point-five-extension-framework/book) as a reference-style book.

Chapter 10: **APIs and Webservices** contains 8 pages about XML-RPC.

For real-live examples, [search](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/xml-rpc) the Joomla! Extension Directory.

Comment: Got the book and it did indeed have some solid examples. Thanks!